# Prove that $x^3$ is irrational, then $x$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Above seems to be a very simple proof but I want to verify that by doing by contraposition is of the many right ways to go about it.

This question is in the form $p \rightarrow q$. Definition of a rational number is $a \in \mathbb Z, b \in \mathbb Z_{\ge0}, \space$ and $\space (a \neq b)$ then $\frac{a}{b}$

**Proof by Contrapositive:**

Contrapostive ($\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p)$

$\lnot q \equiv$ $x$ is rational, and $\lnot p \equiv$ $x^3$ is rational.

By stating $x$ is rational then $x = \frac{a}{b}$, then $x^3 = \frac{a^3}{b^3}$, meaning $x$ and $x^3$ are both rational.

Taking the contrapositive of this statement we conclude that if $x$ is irrational then $x^3$ is irrational. $\square$

My question: Is this the right way to go about proving this statement by this method?

Comment: Perfect‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Yes, contraposition is the natural way to prove this. Your proof is fine.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's the _only_ way to do it.

Comment: At the final sentence of the proof, you swapped $x$ with $x^3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @J.G. can you prove that is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Nitpicking: $b\in\Bbb Z_{\color{red}{>}0}$.)

Your proof is fine, except, as pointed out in the comments, the final statement needs $x^3$ swapped with $x$ and *vice versa*.